# Text box designing same as Text box in Silverlight

Tags: html, css

I need to make a textbox with the same designing as we have in silverlight like this:

[image]

Now, the problem is the little triangle at the top right corner of the textbox. I am unable to position it over the textbox. My textbox look something like this:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id='wrap'>
  <input type="text" id="validateInput"/>
  <span>
    <img src="http://snag.gy/C3CDl.jpg" class="triangleimg">
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#validateInput
{
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:20px;
}

.triangleimg
{
  vertical-align:top;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6td6k7jt/) for the code that so far I have tried. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you can change the structure then you can also write css instead of image for arrow [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj56g5ej/)

Comment: Thanks. Its perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use css for arrow if you can change the html structure

```css
#validateInput {
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
#wrap span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #FFFFE0;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <span><input type="text" id="validateInput" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: inline-block;` and `position: relative;` to parent div. 
And `position: absolute;` to child span.

```css
#validateInput
{
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:20px;
}

.triangleimg
{
  vertical-align:top;
  
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <input type="text" id="validateInput"/>
  <span>
    <img src="http://snag.gy/C3CDl.jpg" class="triangleimg">
  </span>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6td6k7jt/4/)

Answer (score 1):

**Ty This**
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6td6k7jt/6/)

```css
body{
  background-color: #EEE;
}
#validateInput
{
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:20px;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.item:after
{
  content:'';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display:block;
  background-image: url('http://i.snag.gy/C3CDl.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="text" id="validateInput" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` for your image and make the `span` as relative. After that use negative left position to make the desired result.

```
 .triangleimg
 {
   vertical-align:top;  
   position:absolute;
   left:-7px;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6td6k7jt/5/)